# render in libgdx can't update the new value to draw

Tags: android, libgdx

I just start libgdx and this looks simple but I don't understand.
My render method in screen object will call the render method from WorldRenderer:

```
public World world;
public void render() {

    spriteBatch.begin();
        drawBlocks();
        drawBob();
    spriteBatch.end();
    if (debug)
        drawDebug();
}
private void drawBob() {
    Bob bob = this.world.getBob();
    Log.e("inside drawBob",this.world.getBob().getPosition().x  +"dadas");
    bobFrame = bob.isFacingLeft() ? bobIdleLeft : bobIdleRight;
    if(bob.getState().equals(State.WALKING)) {
        bobFrame = bob.isFacingLeft() ? walkLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(bob.getStateTime(), true) : walkRightAnimation.getKeyFrame(bob.getStateTime(), true);
    }
    spriteBatch.draw(bobFrame, bob.getPosition().x * ppuX, bob.getPosition().y * ppuY, Bob.SIZE * ppuX, Bob.SIZE * ppuY);
```

// Screen render method

```
void render(float delta) {
       Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1); 
       Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
        controller.update(delta);
        renderer.render();
         }
```

I have a updateBob method to update world's bob position.
here is controller 's update :

```
    public void update(float delta) {
    processInput();
    Vector2 pos = new Vector2(7,7);
    //bob.setPosition(pos);
    bob.getPosition().x += 1;
    bob.update(delta);
}
```

Application create() method

```
    public void create() {
    setScreen(new GameScreen());
    world = new World();
    renderer = new WorldRenderer(world, true);
    controller = new WorldController(world);
    //Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}
```

Inside the method, I updated it and the value change. but the bob's position in render doesn't change, so I cannot make Bob move.
Please tell me where is wrong.

Comment: You are looking at the StarAssault tutorial xD It was also my first tutorial xD First of all i recommend you to use camera, to avoid the `ppuX, ppuY`. Read this http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/OrthographicCamera and this http://www.acamara.es/blog/2012/02/keep-screen-aspect-ratio-with-different-resolutions-using-libgdx/ and if you don't understand it just google for it or ask here. Back to your question: When do you call updateBob method? What is the value of `bob.getPosition().x` in one frame? and what in the other? And do you clear the screen in every render cycle?

Comment: ok, thanks for your tutorial. I update bob when touch down in screen is called, and the value of bob.getPosition().x is the same even i set  bob.getPosition().x +=1 for example. render method here  public void render(float delta) {
  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  //controller.update(delta);
  renderer.render();
  
 }

Comment: So the bob.position.x does not change if you use bob.getPosition().x+=1? `//controller.update(delta);` did you set the update under comment? It would be better if you post the `controller.update(delta)` and the `public void render(float delta)` as code in your question. Just edit it.

Comment: what i wonder here is that in controller you update the bob's but that is controller's bob, not renderer's bob. But you draw the renderer's bob. And it doesn't move

Comment: They have to be the same! You have a World class right? There you have got a Bob and the getBob(). So your render and your controller both need to get the Bob by using world.getBob(), so that they modify the same object!

Comment: Opps! I think I know why already, the render in gamescreen class in not the one will run every circle, so that's while it points to other object. Quite confuse when you call 2 render method but only one is correct :s

Comment: The render of your screen should be called every cycle. There you should manually call update() for your world and then render() your world.

Comment: That 's what documentation said, but i try to put some Log in both render of Screen and ApplicationListener, only the app listener Log every cycle. Then I don't know the purpose of Screen, as said it's game's creen

Comment: Did you set "application.setScreen(new Gamescreen())"?

Comment: yes I did. The application will manage the render time (means to update every cycle), GameScreen to manage input, the Bob is managed by controller. How can I link between them. I saw you put the world inside both controller and renderer

Comment: If you set the Screen the Application will call render of your Screen every cycle. In the render of your screen you have to call update() on the controller. The GameScreen should not handle the Input, IMHO, it should be done by the controller. In your update() you can check if you should move (any key is pressed) and at the speed*deltaTime to Bobs position. Then you should render everything. The Bobsprite/Texture needs to be drawn at bob.posX and bob.posY. Thats it, everything is connected and should work.

Comment: and something I am not sure. I call setScreen(new GameScreen()); but doesn't seem to call render() in GameScreen class in every game frame. Only if I call render in application

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47958/discussion-between-le-duy-khanh-and-springrbua)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion in the chat we found the problem. If you override the `render()` in your `ApplicationListener`, you have to call `super.render()` to be sure, that `render(float delta)` in `Screen` is called. The same should count for `pause()` and other methods of `ApplicationListener` to.

Comment: really useful for beginner to understand